# spring Quartz scheduler with cron expression

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I want to schedule a job class that checks if a boolean var changed to true or , which is initially not set to any value, using cron expression every night at sometime(say 1'o clock).The scheduler should quit the job if var is set to true or false, otherwise continue running the job at schedule for the max of 15 days & then set it to true automatically. I think IoC container pattern is suitable to do this. Please provide a brief picture of the whole code to implement this.

Answer (score 4):

Spring has built-in scheduling capabilities.  While the full implementation is in your court, here is an example of a scheduled method, in this case for 1AM every day:

```
private Boolean scheduleToggle = null;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 01 * * ?")
public void myScheduledJob() {
    if(scheduleToggle != null) {
        return;
    } else {
        // run the job
        scheduleToggle = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

For a full explanation and configuration details, see: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html